# What's the difference between incalcitrant and recalcitrant

Tags: adjectives

The word that leaps to mind for me is "incalcitrant", but when I try to look it up online I get odd definitions like this:

> As adjectives the difference between recalcitrant and incalcitrant is that recalcitrant is marked by a stubborn unwillingness to obey authority while incalcitrant is recalcitrant.

(from [here](https://wikidiff.com/recalcitrant/incalcitrant))

And yet *incalcitrant* is not listed as a synonym of *recalcitrant*.

Is there a difference between the meaning or usage of the two words?

Comment: Sorry, but research needs to be from more than one reputable dictionary. I'm not convinced that anything with *wiki* in its name qualifies (except **possibly** Wikipedia itself). For example, Cambridge doesn't list [incalcitrant](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/english/?q=incalcitrant) at all.

Comment: I don't believe there is such a word.

Comment: Quite possible. I wonder if I was mashing _intransigent_ and _recalcitrant_ together by mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some dictionaries (like [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/incalcitrant)) do list "incalcitrant" as a synonym for "recalcitrant." But "incalcitrant" is extremely uncommon, as [Ngram Viewer shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=incalcitrant%2Crecalcitrant&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).